# Write a query and user defined function in Esper

Tags: sequence, complex-event-processing, esper

I am trying to create an EPL statement that will show whether an order is possible or not.

There are two Events, EventA(processed) and EventB(non processed).

create schema EventA(type string, percentCompleted integer);
create schema EventB(type string);

The statement should match all processed elements, based on the type(string) of the element. The result should contain a Boolean value, which indicates whether an order should be processed or not.

I have got the statement below to return true when a successful match is made(and an order can be placed). However, I would also like to return a false when an order can not be placed.

Case tested here:
http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html

```
   create schema EventA(type string, percentCompleted integer);  
   create schema EventB(type string);

   @Name('Out') select * from pattern [every a=EventA -> every  b=EventB(a.type = b.type AND a.percentCompleted > 20) ]
```

Sequence:

```
  EventA={type="1",percentCompleted=0}  
  EventA={type="2",percentCompleted=0}  
  EventA={type="1",percentCompleted=20}   
  EventA={type="1",percentCompleted=40}  
  EventB={type="1"}
```

Result: (Only returns a true result):

```
  Out-output={a={EventA={type='1', percentCompleted=40}}, b={EventB={type='1'}}}
```

I want my statement to return TRUE and "type" instead of the whole result, and also I want the query to return FALSE and "type" when a.percentCompleted < 20.

Answer (score 0):

How long would percent completed need to remain below 20 for it to indicate FALSE? Or is the idea here to get a FALSE every time? Either way it may be easiest for you to just write a second EPL and attach the same listener. Either that or write the query as a join.

Comment: Yes the idea is to get false every time. Actually, I am a bit confused, could you please state the query for this case.

Comment: 'EPStatement cepStatement1 = cepAdm.createEPL("select * from pattern [every a=EventA -> every  b=EventB(a.type = b.type AND a.percentCompleted > 20) ]");cepStatement1.addListener(new CEPListener1());'
----------------------------------------------------
EPStatement cepStatement2 = cepAdm.createEPL("select * from pattern [every a=EventA -> b=EventB(a.type = b.type AND a.percentCompleted <= 20) ]");    

        cepStatement2.addListener(new CEPListener2());
--------------------------------------------------------------
Is this fine????

Comment: And how can I check only with the latest value of EventA, and not all the previous ones.